# Manifest.yml is not being updated with assets:precompile - Rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to make sure that I'm serving compressed css and js files using Rails asset pipeline. I've set it all up nicely and things are precompiling happily - and also syncing happily to S3 where I'm serving them using Amazon's CloudFront CDN.

I'm serving the application.css and application.js like so:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application"
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

The problem, in a nutshell: **The MD5-suffixed files are not being output in the application layout - only the raw application.css and application.js**

This gets a bit stranger: **all of the images have an MD5 stamp**. The CSS/JS files do not.

Here's my production.config:

```
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
  config.assets.compress = true
  # Fallback to compile on demand
  # config.assets.compile = true
  #config.assets.precompile += %w(application.css application.js)
  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
  #push the assets to amazon
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    if request.ssl?
      "https://tekpub-assets.s3.amazonaws.com"
    else
      "http://tekpub-assets.s3.amazonaws.com"
    end
  } 

  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

The infuriating thing about this whole process is that **I can see the gzipped/digested files** - they're right there in my assets directory. All of em - the CSS and JS files as well.

However my manifest.yml file is only updated like so:

```
---
application.js: application.js
application.css: application.css
```

There are no errors when I run precompile - in fact everything looks rather peachy:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Resolved collector.newrelic.com to 204.93.223.153
AssetSync: using /Volumes/Fatty/Sites/tpub6/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Resolved collector.newrelic.com to 204.93.223.153
AssetSync: using /Volumes/Fatty/Sites/tpub6/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
AssetSync: Syncing.
Using: Directory Search of /Volumes/Fatty/Sites/tpub6/public/assets
AssetSync: Done.
```

Thank you for any pointers/shoves/tips.

Answer (score 14):

OK, I found the answer: If the asset pipeline can't compile a file (or file type), it will fail silently, in Ruby/Rails style.

In my case there were 2 problems: there was a "." in a js file name (bootstrap.min.js) - it didn't like that, which I suppose makes some sense since it uses file names to figure out how to process the file (file.css.erb, for example).

The next one is a file type that it doesn't know what to do with. Due to some blindness and stupidity with moving files around, I had a stray YAML file in my assets/images directory. That choked the processor making assets:precompile fail ... again ... silently.

The way I found this out was to create an empty Rails project and compile the assets from scratch. That's how I found the JS file issue as well as the dumb YAML file.

Comment: Because this problem was being caused due to the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem, updating the gem from the git repo with `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'` solved this issue for me.